# How can I create a root user from the start of installing Ubuntu?

Tags: permissions, root

How can I create a root user from the start of Ubuntu installation? When I tried it, it showed that this user name has already been reserved.

Comment: Do you mean `sudo` user? https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-a-sudo-user-on-ubuntu/

Comment: If you want a root user by default use another OS than Ubuntu that uses the root model. CentOS, SUSE.

Comment: You don't need to create a root user; it is created automatically, which is why you can't create one since it already exists. But that's probably not your real question...

Comment: the best way is, after creating the normal account, log in to the root account and completely remove the normal account, and also what like normal account related files it creates. but how to? I want others for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The user root already exists by default when a Linux system is created, or at least, a user must exist with UID 0 who has all permissions and owns most of the system files. Traditionally this user is called root. You do not need to create that user.

When you install Ubuntu, you are prompted to create a user for yourself. This is because it is inadvisable to run the system as root, because root always has all permissions and programs run as root may do whatever they want, which is a security risk. Running commands and other programs as an unprivileged user wherever possible is safer. But, the user you create at installation is not limited in their rights. That user is automatically made a member of the group `sudo` and is allowed to run any command as root by using the `sudo` program. This means you can make use of `sudo` to do anything you want on the system, even to run whole shells and other programs as root, as [SteveInBavaria](https://askubuntu.com/a/1137652/527764) pointed out.

Ubuntu is slightly different from many other Linux distros in its approach, because it disables logging in as root by not setting a password for root. On many Linux systems, when you want to elevate privileges, you become the root user by typing `su -` or just `su` in a terminal. The `su` (switch user) command allows you to log in as another user in a shell. You must enter the password of the user you want to log in as, not your own password. On Ubuntu `su` fails because root has no password. You can "fix" this by setting a password for root, but this is discouraged and not necessary since `sudo` provides all privileges. You can even run the `su` command as root by typing `sudo su`. Then you type your own password and become root. However, since `sudo` provides a way to open a root shell there is no need to run the `su` program with it for this purpose. You can simply use `sudo -i`.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu by default, you cannot log in as root. You log in as a user and providing you are in the sudoers group, which will be the case for the user you create during a new installation, you can run a command as root using the `sudo` command before the program or action you want to perform. For instance.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

There is also the option of typing `sudo -i` in a terminal and after entering your password you can start a root shell. But you should only do this if you absolutely need a root shell for some reason.

Comment: This does not answer the question asked.

Comment: @fkraiem There is no answer to the question as it was asked except "You can't". So I did my best to answer what I thought the questioner was really asking, just as you did above.

Comment: Not every question can or should be answered. If a question is unclear or otherwise unanswerable, you can comment to ask for a clarification, downvote, vote to close, or just leave it alone. But it does not make it okay to post an answer that's not an answer.

Comment: @fkraiem I like to help people and I felt I knew what Kawil was asking. I don't think my answer did any harm, did it? And someone upvoted it. I'm sorry but I don't understand the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

sudo passwd root

After entering your sudo password you will be prompted to create a password for root. Once you have created the root password, then from a terminal you can use the su command to switch to being the root user for your task.

Comment: While this is possible, it's also bad advice to create a root password.